# In R with dplyr, how to aggregate one colum values if repeated dates are duplicated, by group

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have a > 30,000 rows tibble with ID colums, dates and acts. Sometimes, for an ID, two acts are registered the very same day. In that case would like to aggregate those acts.

Please find below a minimal working example (MWE):

```
> id <- c ("N02", "N02", "N02", "N02", "N03", "N03", "N05", "N05", "N05", "N05")
> date_1 <- c ("2008-03-15", "2008-03-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-07-15", "2014-03-06", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-13")
> act <- c ("YYYY050", "ZZNL040", "YYYY050", "ZZNL040", "ZZNL040", "ZZNL040", "ZZNL065", "ZZNL065", "ZZNL040", "ZZNL065")
> date_2 <- c ("2008-03-15", "2008-03-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-07-15", "2014-03-06", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-13")
> df1 <- data.frame (id, date_1, act, date_2)
> df1
    id     date_1     act     date_2
1  N02 2008-03-15 YYYY050 2008-03-15
2  N02 2008-03-15 ZZNL040 2008-03-15
3  N02 2008-04-15 YYYY050 2008-04-15
4  N02 2008-04-15 ZZNL040 2008-04-15
5  N03 2008-06-15 ZZNL040 2008-06-15
6  N03 2008-07-15 ZZNL040 2008-07-15
7  N05 2014-03-06 ZZNL065 2014-03-06
8  N05 2014-03-07 ZZNL065 2014-03-07
9  N05 2014-03-07 ZZNL040 2014-03-07
10 N05 2014-03-13 ZZNL065 2014-03-13
```

In present MWE, `ID` `N02` has `act` `YYYY050` and `ZZNL040` the same day `2008-03-15`.

In that case of mutiple acts the very same day, I would like aggregate the act values. I need to preserve the tibble structure id est `date_1` and `date_2` which are sometimes different for further calculations and, therefore use dplyr.

My desired output would be:

```
> id <- c ("N02", "N02", "N03", "N03", "N05", "N05", "N05")
> date_1 <- c ("2008-03-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-07-15", "2014-03-06", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-13")
> act <- c ("YYYY050/ZZNL040", "YYYY050/ZZNL040","ZZNL040", "ZZNL040", "ZZNL065", "ZZNL065/ZZNL040", "ZZNL065")
> date_2 <- c ("2008-03-15", "2008-04-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-07-15", "2014-03-06", "2014-03-07", "2014-03-13")
> df2 <- data.frame (id, date_1, act, date_2)
> df2
   id     date_1             act     date_2
1 N02 2008-03-15 YYYY050/ZZNL040 2008-03-15
2 N02 2008-04-15 YYYY050/ZZNL040 2008-04-15
3 N03 2008-06-15         ZZNL040 2008-06-15
4 N03 2008-07-15         ZZNL040 2008-07-15
5 N05 2014-03-06         ZZNL065 2014-03-06
6 N05 2014-03-07 ZZNL065/ZZNL040 2014-03-07
7 N05 2014-03-13         ZZNL065 2014-03-13
```

Any idea ?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Charles.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(id, date_1, date_2) %>%
  summarise(act = paste(act, collapse = '/')) %>%
  select(1, 2, 4, 3)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, date_1 [7]
#>   id    date_1     act             date_2    
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>           <chr>     
#> 1 N02   2008-03-15 YYYY050/ZZNL040 2008-03-15
#> 2 N02   2008-04-15 YYYY050/ZZNL040 2008-04-15
#> 3 N03   2008-06-15 ZZNL040         2008-06-15
#> 4 N03   2008-07-15 ZZNL040         2008-07-15
#> 5 N05   2014-03-06 ZZNL065         2014-03-06
#> 6 N05   2014-03-07 ZZNL065/ZZNL040 2014-03-07
#> 7 N05   2014-03-13 ZZNL065         2014-03-13
```

Comment: Could replace last line by: `relocate(act, .after = date_1)`

Comment: How to prevent the following message to appear: `summarise()` has grouped output by 'anonyme', 'rt_date_entree'. You can override using the `.groups` argument? Thank you

Comment: You can do as the message says. Change to `summarise(act = paste(act, collapse = '/'), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: Despite if I don't really understand the purpose of the message and its disappearance after your trick that works well. Thank you Allan.

Comment: @CharlesLDN it's just a message to remind you what the grouping variables are, because it is possible to get confused about this if you are using a long set of instructions in a dplyr pipe. Personally, I dislike it too and hope it's turned off in future versions.